# Custom Liking Function - Do I need User Login?

Tags: php

I've recently implemented a working custom liking/disliking function for my comics site.

but I feel it’s pushing me towards implementing a login system for all users… which I really don’t want to have to do (for my sake and my fans' sake)

Currently, the function works by:

> 1) Passing button value (id = 'like' or id = 'dislike') via Jquery to
>   php script
>
> 2) script will first check if an ip exists in the database against
>   that given comic id... if not it will insert user's IP and current
>   comic ID and increment total likes for a given comic id... if it
>   already exists, it will remove that user’s information and decrement
>   total likes.

The issue is, what happens if multiple fans “like” or “dislike” a comic from the same IP (net café, etc), or the same user goes and likes a comic from another computer… 
So I was thinking the way to solve that would be generate a unique value for the user’s session and store it against their IP.

But what if that user wanted to come back at a later point after their unique session ID has expired and change their like to a dislike… how would the computer know it’s them? 
Or what happens if the same user expires their session ID somehow (logs off then logs back in, closes browser, etc) and now can vote multiple times?

In this case, do I have to create a login system?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since IP addresses can change pretty dynamically for the general user, it's tough to implement this without creating a login system. I don't think you would need to get too technical with it. A user database could just have user_id, username, salt, and hashed password, and then your like/dislike database would use the user_id instead of an IP. Then users could login from anywhere and things would work.

To log them in, just generating a form that creates a session with their username could be sufficient. Might take a while but if done right initially it will allow you to scale without much added effort.

Comment: Dane, thanks for the answer. I wasn't concerned with the effort on my end, but more so the usability of my fans. Most comics sites don't require you to log in to like comics.

Comment: Consider using a persistent cookie scheme instead, that way you'll at least be able to differentiate users MOST of the time. When they first enter the site, check for their cookie, and store the cookie value along with the comics they've liked/disliked in a database. Set the cookie if they don't already have one.